# How to automatically center the components used in JFrame as the frame is resized?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, jcomponent

I want my widgets to be at the center of the `JFrame` regardless of its size (means either frame size is small or larger components should be at center of the frame).

How to set the components at center dynamically on resizing frame?

Comment: 1. depends of if the space between JFrames border and widgets borders stay unchanged or resizing is somehow proportionally, 2. voting to close as too broad

Comment: try to use split container inside the Jfram which rearrange its widgets after re-size the window

Comment: @mKorbel I didn't get what u said can u pleaseelaborate it. i just wanna know how keep my wigdets at center of the frame if frame is of any size

Comment: @ِAllloush can you provide me good example of it ?

Comment: Can u tell me which IDE are you working on ?

Comment: @ِAllloush   eclipse

Comment: Do u use any drag and drop library to help you in the design ?

Comment: @ِAllloushyup i am using window builder nothing else to drag and drop

Answer (score 2):

> So please tell me how to set the widgets at center dynamically on
>   resizing frame in java

- Swing has [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) not widgets

> i want my widgets to be at the center of the jframe regardless of its
>   size(means either jframe size is small or larger widgets should be at
>   center of the frame).

- easiest by using [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html), proportional resize could be by using [BoxLayout, GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

.

[image]

.

[image]

.

[image]

.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JFrameAndBorderLayout {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame and BorderLayout");
    private JPanel panelWest = new JPanel();
    private JPanel panelEast = new JPanel();
    private JPanel panelNorth = new JPanel();
    private JPanel panelSouth = new JPanel();
    private JPanel panelCenter = new JPanel() {
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 300);
        }

    };

    public JFrameAndBorderLayout() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panelWest, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(panelEast, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(panelNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(panelSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panelCenter.setBackground(Color.RED);
        frame.add(panelCenter);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrameAndBorderLayout fs = new JFrameAndBorderLayout();
            }
        });
    }
}
```